# why the basis generates the ideal as an R-module?

Tags: ring-theory

This is from Page 82 of Rotman's homological algebra book.

Definition: Let k be a commutative ring. Then a ring R is a k-algebra if R is a k-module satisfying: a(rs) = (ar)s = r(as) for all a in k and r,s in R.

If k is a field and R is a finite-dim k-algebra, then every left or right ideal I in R is a subspace of R. A basis of I generates I as a k-module; a fortiori, it generates I as an R-module, and so I is finitely generated.

I don't quite follow why the basis generates I as an R-module as the scalars are now from R. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $R$ has identity element, we obtain a ring homomorphism $\varphi:k\to R$ by $\lambda \mapsto \lambda 1$.

Already the $k$-linear combination of the basis elements give all elements of $I$, and these are all $R$-linear combinations (through $\varphi$) as well.